# How to ignore a character through strtok?

Tags: c++, strtok

In the below code i would like to also ignore the character ” . But after adding that in i still get “Mr_Bishop” as my output.

I have the following code:

```
    ifstream getfile;
    getfile.open(file,ios::in);
        char data[256];
    char *line;
    //loop till end of file                   
    while(!getfile.eof())
    {
            //get data and store to variable data
            getfile.getline(data,256,'\n');

        line = strtok(data," ”");
        while(line != NULL)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            line = strtok(NULL," ");
        }
    }//end of while loop
```

my file content :

```
hello 7 “Mr_Bishop”
hello 10 “0913823”
```

Basically all i want my output to be :

```
hello
7
Mr_Bishop
hello
10
0913823
```

With this code i only get :

```
hello
7
"Mr_Bishop"
hello
10
"0913823"
```

Thanks in advance! :)

I realise i have made an error in the inner loop missing out the quote. But now i receive the following output :

```
hello
7
Mr_Bishop
�
hello
10
0913823
�
```

any help? thanks! :)

Comment: Please dont use `strtok`.  It sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a *very* careful look at your code:

```
    line = strtok(data," ”");
```

Notice how the quotes lean at different angles (well mine do, I guess hopefully your font shows the same thing). You have included only the closing double quote in your `strtok()` call. However, Your data file has:

```
hello 7 “Mr_Bishop”
```

which has *two* different kinds of quotes. Make sure you're using all the right characters, whatever "right" is for your data.

**UPDATE**: Your data is probably UTF-8 encoded (that's how you got those leaning double quotes in there) and you're using `strtok()` which is completely unaware of UTF-8 encoding. So it's probably doing the wrong thing, splitting up the multibyte UTF-8 characters, and leaving you with rubbish at the end of the line.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply! i realise my code has an error. i forgot to put the quotes in the inner loop. hence it does not show. but now it produces this � at the end of the line

Comment: You know, your data is probably UTF-8 encoded (that's how you got those leaning double quotes in there) and you're using `strtok()` which is completely unaware of UTF-8 encoding. So it's probably doing the wrong thing, splitting up the multibyte UTF-8 characters, and leaving you with rubbish at the end of the line.

Comment: also the proper escape sequence for " is \", so it's line = strtok(data," \"");

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you used Wordpad or something to generate the file. You should use Notepad or Notepad++ on Windows or similar thing that will create ASCII encoding on Linux. Right now you are using what looks like UTF-8 encoding.

In addition the proper escape sequence for " is \". For instance

```
line = strtok(data," \"");
```

Once you fix your file to be in ASCII encoding, you'll find you missed something in your loop.

```
while(!getfile.eof())
{
        //get data and store to variable data
        getfile.getline(data,256,'\n');

    line = strtok(data," \"");
    while(line != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        line = strtok(NULL," \""); // THIS used to be strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}//end of while loop
```

You missed a set of quotes there.
Correcting the file and this mistake yields the proper output.